# How split string into separate variables based on several characters in Java Script

Tags: javascript

There is a String variable that comes value like the following.

```
"COMPANY=10^INVOICE_ID=100021^"
```

I need to get this into two variables like Company and InvoieId.

What will be possible ways to do that JS?

Answer (score 0):

If this code will be called more than once, let's create a function:

```
const parseInput = (input) => {
  const [company, invoice_id] =
    input.split("^")
      .map(kv => kv.split("=")[1]);

    return {
      company,
      invoice_id
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic way. You can grab any value from `obj`.

```js
const str = "COMPANY=10^INVOICE_ID=100021^"

const obj = {}
const strArr = str.split('^')

strArr.forEach(str => {
    const [key, value] = str.split('=')
    obj[key] = value
})

const {COMPANY, INVOICE_ID } = obj

console.log(INVOICE_ID, COMPANY)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do it via regular expression

[**Regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/m2t4Rm/1)

```js
let str = `COMPANY=10^INVOICE_ID=100021^`
let regex = /(\w+)=\d+/g
let match = regex.exec(str)
while(match){
  console.log(match[1])
  match = regex.exec(str)
}
```